# Circular dependancies between inline files

Tags: c++, templates, inline, circular-dependency

In my math library I'm creating in C++, I have a Quaternion class and a Vector3 class. They are laid out like this:

Vector3.hpp:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
struct Vector3
{
   //...
};

template<typename T>
Vector3<T> operator+(Vector3<T> lhs, Vector3<T> rhs);

#include "Vector3.inl"
```

Vector3.inl

```
template<typename T>
Vector3<T> operator+(Vector3<T> lhs, Vector3<T> rhs)
{
    return Vector3<T>(lhs.x+rhs.x, lhs.y+rhs.y, lhs.z+rhs.z);
}

//...
```

The `Quaternion` class is laid out the same.

At the moment I have the `Quaternion` class using the `Vector3` class for function parameters, so it `#include`s the `Vector3.hpp` header. But now I need to use the `Quaternion` class in my `Vector3` class to implement certain functionality.

Since this is only needed in the implementation of the functions, I'd typically just put the `#include` in the source file, but since I'm using inline files, and they're included in the header, doing so simply causes a bunch of compiler errors because they depend on each other.

How do you solve such a circular dependency when I can only use header/inline files?

Comment: Why do you *have to* use only header/inline files? At least you should consider moving the line `#include "Vector3.inl` from the `Vector3.hpp` to the consuming `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle a circular dependency is to avoid it in the first place! It would be sensible to take some time to reconsider the design, shifting the functionality, splitting classes, and similar.

Let's assume the situation without the circular dependency looks like following:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector{
 ...
};

template<typename T>
struct VectorUser{
   Vector<T> v;
   ...
};
```

The issue of circular dependency can be solved if it can be resolved by means of forward declaration, for example for:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector{
  void printout(const VectorUser<T> &user);
  ...
};
```

Forward declaration of `VectorUser` combined with the implementation of `Vector<T>::printout()` after the declaration of `VectorUser` i.e. in *VectorUser.inl*  (after all, nobody could use Vector without including *VectorUser.h* anyway) yields the desired result:

```
//Vector.h:
template <typename T>
struct VectorUser;


template <typename T>
struct Vector{
  void printout(VectorUser<T> &user);
  ...
};

//VectorUser.h:
template<typename T>
struct VectorUser{...} 
};

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::printout(VectorUser<T> &user){
   user.printout();
}
```

But what if the forward declaration is not enough? For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector{
  VectorUser<T> user;
  ...
};
```

Well, you would not get it to compile even without templates. There are at least two options I see pretty often in code:

1. making `Vector<T>::user` a pointer/reference, so the forward declaration would be sufficient.
2. splitting `Vector<T>` in two classes: the one base class which is used in `VectorUser` and the other derived from it with all functionality depending on `VectorUser`.

I would advocate the second solution, but it maybe not always feasible.